# GooglePlay similar piece of interface

Tags: android, android-layout

What kind of functionality is this ?

[image]

Is it FragmentPagerAdapter ? Is there any predefined styles/functionality to achieve just the same for API 10 ? Show me an example please.

Comment: [Android ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a [`PagerTitleStrip`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip.html) which is used with a [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) (so yes, your thought on `FragmentPagerAdapter` is correct if you want to use `Fragments` -- which you should, but I was lazy when I used it). Simply add the `PagerTitleStrip` as a child of your `ViewPager` like this:

```
<com.android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <com.android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        />
</com.android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

And in your `PagerAdapter` that you write, be sure to override the `getPageTitle()` method. Android should handle everything else for you, although you'll have to style it manually if you want a custom font as shown, and the font color and background as shown.

It is included in the support library (right-click your project in Eclipse, choose Android Tools > Add Compatibility Package) and is compatible all the way back to API Level 4, so you will have no issues using it for API Level 10. The JakeWharton library being linked is overkill if you simply need the swiping title functionality -- his was developed before Google added the `PagerTitleStrip` to the compatibility library -- but does have some additional styles that you can use if so needed.

Comment: Well I did not know about the PagerTitleStrip so thanks for that. Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 1):

Jake Wharton has the ViewPagerIndicator if you would like - provides support for lower than 3.0 versions.

http://viewpagerindicator.com/